# Append a dictionary to a nested dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

my two dictionaries look like

```
d1={123456 :{u'xyz':u'987'}, 892019:{u'kjl':u'0902'}, 102930491:{u'plm':u'019240',u'kop':u'09829'}}
d2= {u'random_no_1': [u'123456', u'892019'], u'random_no_2': [u'102930491']}
```

And I would like to have a combined dictionary. Something like this.

```
d3 = {'random_no_1':{123456:{xyz:987}, 892019:{kjl:0902}}, 'random_no_2':{102930491:{plm:019240,kop:09829}}
```

I tried this loop, but it only prints first to keys.

```
result = {}
for k, v in d1.items():
  if isinstance(v, list):
     result[k] = {k: d2.get(k) for k in v}
  else:
      result[k] = {v: d2.get(v)}
```

So my result looks like this.

```
result = {'random_no_1':{123456 : None}, 892019: None}, 'random_no_2':{102930491: None}
```

I think the problem is in the loop, any advice will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Shouldn't you be iterating `d2` in the outer for loop and `d1` in the comprehension?

Comment: You use `k` as a loop variable twice

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: You use the same variable `k` both in `for k, v in d1.items()` and `for k in v`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with one-liner

```
result = {key: {val: d1.get(val) for val in d2[key]} for key in d2}
```

Comment: says invalid syntax :(

Comment: @mfweewee, fixed a typo.

Comment: Nope, still none values, where there should be actual numbers. :(

Comment: Is it possible since in one dictionary one value is printed 123456 and in another is '123456' and python doesn't recognize?

Comment: In your original question both were integers.

Comment: I know i made a mistake. im sorry :)

Comment: You can simply cast a string `s` to the integer with `int(s)`.

Comment: It says its not working, cause its a list? Tried to convert strings from d2 to intigers.

Comment: Solved it wit your help. Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 0):

Using an iteration & `dict()`.

**Demo:**

```
d1={123456 :{"xyz":987}, 892019:{"kjl":902}, 102930491:{"plm":19240,"kop":9829}}
d2= {'random_no_1': [123456, 892019], '3.9.1.3': [102930491]}

d3 = {}
for k,v in d2.items():
    d3[k] = {}
    for i in v:
        d3[k][i] = d1.get(i)
print(d3)
```

*Or a one-liner*

```
d3 = dict((k, {i: d1.get(i) for i in v}) for k,v in d2.items())
```

**Output:**

```
{'random_no_1': {123456: {'xyz': 987}, 892019: {'kjl': 902}}, '3.9.1.3': {102930491: {'kop': 9829, 'plm': 19240}}}
```

Comment: Still a lot of none values, where there should be actual values.

Comment: The none values should be from `d1.get(i)` Check if the elements in the list have a value in `d1`

Comment: Yeah they do. :(

Comment: Is it possible since in one dictionary one value is printed 123456 and in another is '123456' and python doesn't recognize?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
>>> d1
{123456: {u'xyz': u'987'}, 102930491: {u'kop': u'09829', u'plm': u'019240'}, 892019: {u'kjl': u'0902'}}
>>> d2
{u'random_no_2': [u'102930491'], u'random_no_1': [u'123456', u'892019']}
>>> {key:value for key,value in d2.iteritems()}
{u'random_no_2': [u'102930491'], u'random_no_1': [u'123456', u'892019']}
>>> {key:[item for item in value] for key,value in d2.iteritems()}
{u'random_no_2': [u'102930491'], u'random_no_1': [u'123456', u'892019']}
>>> {key:[d1.get(int(item)) for item in value] for key,value in d2.iteritems()}
{u'random_no_2': [{u'kop': u'09829', u'plm': u'019240'}], u'random_no_1': [{u'xyz': u'987'}, {u'kjl': u'0902'}]}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use a nested dictionary comprehension with `itertools.groupby`:

```
import itertools
d1={123456 :{u'xyz':u'987'}, 892019:{u'kjl':u'0902'}, 102930491:{u'plm':u'019240',u'kop':u'09829'}}
d2= {u'random_no_1': [u'123456', u'892019'], u'random_no_2': [u'102930491']}
def sort_key(x):
  return [a for a, b in d2.items() if str(x[0]) in b][0]

new_d = [[a, list(b)] for a, b in itertools.groupby(sorted(d1.items(), key=sort_key), key=sort_key)]
last_d = {a:dict(b) for a, b in new_d}
```

Output:

```
{'random_no_1': {123456: {'xyz': '987'}, 892019: {'kjl': '0902'}}, 'random_no_2': {102930491: {'plm': '019240', 'kop': '09829'}}}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for you answer. It says that list index is out of range.

Comment: @mfweewee Strange, I am not receiving that error. Can you post the input you are using that gives that error?